# What are some good examples of well-illustrated web apps?

Tags: web-app

Sites out there like [Vimeo](http://www.vimeo.com) and [CarWoo](http://www.carwoo.com) do a really good job of incorporating illustrations as primary design elements. Are there any others out there that you like?

Answer (score 3):

[Gowalla](http://gowalla.com/) use illustrations for their badges / awards

Answer (score 3):

**Area 51**

- [Home page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) (don't forget to scroll to the bottom)
- [Example site page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5728)
- [FAQ page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)

Answer (score 3):

[Carbonmade](http://carbonmade.com) has great illustrations all over its marketing site, which do a great job of setting it apart from competing sites.

Comment: I'm not too crazy about Carbonmade's marketing site. Yea, it's very pretty and the illustrations are great, but it's too girly. It looks like it's designed for 16-year-old girls, not for creative professionals. I mean, if I hadn't seen carbonmade portfolios before, I would have confused it for a DeviantArt-type site for girls. The portfolios themselves look nice and clean and serious/professional. But the marketing site gives a completely different feel. I suspect this has actually deterred a significant number of male prospects from signing up.

Answer (score 3):

[Get Satisfaction](http://getsatisfaction.com/explore/introduction) has a lot of well-integrated illustrations. They're very beautiful and detailed, but they're not distracting or gaudy.

Answer (score 2):

Brightkite still uses illustrations but not as extensivly as before.

http://brightkite.com/account/signup

Answer (score 2):

http://ux.stackexchange.com

:)

Answer (score 2):

I like these:

- http://dropr.com/
- http://www.cascadebreweryco.com.au/
- http://www.justdot.gr/
- http://www.amazeelabs.com/
- http://dc2009.drupalcon.org/

And some more, woo!

- http://webdesignledger.com/inspiration/35-inspiring-examples-of-illustration-in-web-design

Answer (score 2):

http://carsonified.com/ make great use of illustration on thier own site and and sites they build eg: http://chirp.twitter.com/